# Laravel homestead and vagrant setup not working

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I followed the original documentation for vagrant and homestead but every site.app:8000 you visit it just keeps loading and nothing happens. Is there an error within this configuration files?

**Homestead.yaml**

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Developer/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel

sites:
    - map: hello-world.local
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel/hello-world/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

**hosts**

```
192.168.10.10    hello-world.local
```

**vagrant up log**

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 5.0.20
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/nikla/Developer/homestead
    default: /home/vagrant/laravel => /Users/nikla/Developer/laravel
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

**nmap log**

```
Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-29 22:55 ART
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.10
Host is up (0.00063s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
5432/tcp open  postgresql
9000/tcp open  cslistener

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.19 seconds
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `:8000`. Considering the setup you've shown, once you `vagrant up`, you should be able to just point your browser to `http://test.app`

Comment: [http://arhamzul.com/how-to-install-homestead-and-laravel-on-windows-10/](http://arhamzul.com/how-to-install-homestead-and-laravel-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Have you run "vagrant provision" after editing the yaml file?

Comment: Yes I did. I also rebooted the host machine and started vagrant with the yaml file already configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check your "vagrant up" log and I see all things ok. I have compared your log with my machine's log and is similar.

Try to open the IP in the web browser (change the IP with your Vagrant VM IP):

```
http://192.168.10.10/
```

Do you have some firewall, antivirus or another software that could disable the communication?

Try to execute a nmap to see wich ports are open. I paste my nmap, from my host machine to my virtual machine, so you can see wich ports are open.

```
$ nmap 192.168.10.10

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-30 01:48 Hora de verano romance
Nmap scan report for homestead.app (192.168.10.10)
mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
Host is up (0.0019s latency).
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
5432/tcp open  postgresql
9000/tcp open  cslistener
MAC Address: 08:00:27:CD:99:8C (Cadmus Computer Systems)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 21.83 seconds
```

Comment: That's progress, I'm getting "No input file specified." when entering 192.168.10.10. Maybe is something wrong with permissions? I previously chmod -R 777 on ~/developer/laravel folder. I just updated the post with the nmap log.

Comment: Ok, now you can reach to the Vagrant VM machine, but not to the correct folder. 
Check if the /home/vagrant/laravel/hello-world/public/ folder exists and if it has the correct elements (assets, .htaccess,index.php, robots.txt, web.config), the permissions and then check this forum: http://laravel.io/forum/06-04-2014-no-input-file-specified-using-homestead

Comment: Now I get the laravel 5 index when entering the IP. But going to .local doesnt work and the hosts file is setup properly. Any idea?

Comment: "192.168.10.10    hello-world.local" must work. Now I am thinking that could be some problem with the nginx virtual hosts. Can you paste the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ content: "ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/" and content of your domain virtual host "more /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/hello-world.local" ??

Comment: it must, but it doesn't. I don't have nginx on the host, so on the virtual machine I get properly listed: hello-world.local.

Comment: On an extra note, I have to create de laravel project after doing vagrant up so I when I type the vagrant IP on the browser I get the laravel index. If I do it before, the browser just keeps thinking. No way to enter through hello-world.local yet.

Comment: You have the nginx on the Vagrant VM. Can you paste the output of this commands executed in the Vagrant VM???

Comment: Yeah, thats the output of the vm. Just one line: hello-world.local.

Comment: It's working now. There was a problem with the hosts file apparently; I made a new one on the desktop and replaced the one at /etc. Is there a way to create an alias called "vm" to cd into my homestead folder and run vagrant up?

Comment: I paste my Laravel alias http://www.jesusamieiro.com/laravel-bash-alias/

Answer (score 0):

Check:

- The id_rsa.pub and the id_rsa are in this folder.
- The /Users/nikla/Developer/laravel folder exists in your host machine.
- The /home/vagrant/laravel exists in your Vagrant VM machine. You can check it login in the machine using the command "vagrant ssh".
- Try to access to the http://test.app without the 8000 port.

I don't see the database in your Homestead.yaml file. You should have the next text in this file

```
databases:
    - homestead
```

Comment: All of that was checked, I'm using OSX. Do you any other tip?

Comment: Can you paste the console output when you execute "vagrant up"?